# One-word command to search for a file

Tags: command-line, find

I know there's a command to search for a file anywhere. It's a quite simple, 1 word command. Sadly, I forgot what it is.

So, let's say I want to search for a file name `testingthis`. The file could be anywhere in the system. How would I do it?

Comment: In your `/home/<user_name>` is a file called `bash_history` and it is a godsend. You can even clean it of duplicates and keep it from saving duplicates. I keep it saved and even import it across machines by moving it through my own network of keeping a reasonably recent backup "in the cloud." I've got stuff that I typed in bash from years ago! (This may help you in the future. I find it helps me more often than I care to admit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `locate`

```
locate testingthis
```

or `find`

```
find / -name testingthis
```

For locate the system has to build a database of files. If the database is not built it will not find anything. Also if you add new files they will not be found until the database is updated again. You can updated the database with `updatedb`.

Comment: locate is the one I was searching for. Thank you.